# Use curl to do the same thing as wget command below

Tags: curl, wget

If I want use "curl" to do the same thing as below command, how to do it.

```
wget -r -l1 --no-parent --http-user abc--http-passwd 12345"https://abc.com/projects/s/packaging/builds/1.2.1/201311191121/software/" -A "o*txt*" -P /tmp_endpoint/
```

Comment: Why not simply use wget?

Comment: I only have remote terminal access to a mac, have difficulty in installing xcode. So it's difficult to install wget, have to use curl

Comment: You don't have to install xcode in order to use `wget`?

Comment: brew install wget
Warning: No developer tools installed.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.

Comment: I tried two ways to install wget, but both of them tell me that I need install xcode

Comment: Have you tried to download and install wget not using any package manager? You could also try to install the commandline tools using: `xcode-select --install` from the terminal. Here is a guide how to install wget without homebrew or macports: http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/22/install-wget-mac-os-x/